# Magit - How to update a branch without using checkout?

Tags: magit

While working on a project, it is necessary to pull some branches from remote and merge into current branch.

To update another branch, we have to

- Stash local changes on current branch
- Checkout to required branch (say `foo`)
- Pull changes
- Switch back to previous branch
- Pop stash

All these steps can be done with single command on terminal using

```
git fetch origin foo:foo
```

How to do the same with magit in single step?

Comment: `: fetch origin foo:foo` (not intended to be facetious -- I'm just pointing out that you can run *arbitrary* git commands from inside git).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @phils valid observation, there is `f` `o` for `fetch other`, you can then give it `origin` and then `foo`. This will update the `origin/foo` branch, rather than the `foo` branch.

Or you can use `f` `r` for `fetch refspec` and give it `origin` and `foo:foo` which will do exactly what your command line does.

Comment: Excellent. Is it possible to auto populate `foo:foo`, instead of typing them everytime?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to fetch just that one branch instead of everything? The current interface was designed with the assumptions that just fetching everything isn't much of a deal because it is more convenient to tell git "get it all" as opposed to "get... wait... ah yes, /this/".

Comment: @tarsius It would be great if all remotes can be fetched at once. However i wanted all PR's of a repo, i have updated `    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` in git config. Now when i run `f`,  `r`, `origin`, it just lists all available PR's and I have to type `branch:branch` everytime to fetch a branch.
`

Comment: @ChillarAnand `f` `u` will fetch all the configured branches, just like `git fetch origin`.